# SceneKit adaptive subdivision

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm having trouble trying to implement adaptive subdivision in SceneKit. The results I'm expecting should be similar to what's seen in the 2017 SceneKit demo for WWDC of the Fox mesh. I would like it to work in ARKit. Do I have to specify my `pointOfView.camera` as any factor in the process of initializing the subdivision, or do I have to calculate the length away from the camera to model at all times adjusting my `subdivisionLevel` in a SceneKit `renderer` delegate method?

```
let tessellator = SCNGeometryTessellator()
tessellator.edgeTessellationFactor = 3.0
tessellator.insideTessellationFactor = 3.0
newNode.geometry?.tessellator = tessellator
tessellator.smoothingMode = .pnTriangles
tessellator.isAdaptive = true
tessellator.maximumEdgeLength = 50
        
modelNode.geometry?.wantsAdaptiveSubdivision = true
modelNode.geometry?.subdivisionLevel = 1
```

See Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry/1524177-subdivisionlevel) or the [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/) (at 23:00).

Comment: Look into the dolly command also mentioned in this video. I am pretty sure they used it to show what is happening in the demo.